# How to compile clojurescript to javascript?

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

[image]

I have a big question to authors of clojurescript. And to all clojurescript community.

ClojureScript tutorial is unefficient and broken. It doesn't help with this problem. (see picture)

How to compile clojurescript to javascript?

Comment: add a link to tutorial you are using

Comment: This question, as stated, is not a very good one. Which tutorial? What steps did you take to get to this stack trace?

That said, I can completely sympathize with the frustration. I eventually found a clojurescript routine that works fine for me, but it took quite a while and a lot of trial and error. Almost, but not quite all the clojurescript resources I've been able to find are as helpful as mud.

Comment: it seems that tutorial is https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#using-clojurescript-on-a-web-page

Comment: O'Reilly's *Clojurescript: Up and Running* by Sierra and VanderHart is a good resources for getting started.  Given how short the book is, one might feel that it's not worth the money.  I do think it's worth what it costs, since, as galdre points out, many of the free resources on the net do a poor job of providing an initial understanding of how to set up and use Clojurescripot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [lein-mies](https://github.com/swannodette/mies) template

```
→  lein new mies hello-world
Retrieving mies/lein-template/0.4.1/lein-template-0.4.1.pom from clojars
Retrieving mies/lein-template/0.4.1/lein-template-0.4.1.jar from clojars
→  cd hello-world
→  lein cljsbuild auto
Compiling ClojureScript.
Compiling "hello_world.js" from ["src"]...
Successfully compiled "hello_world.js" in 8.025 seconds.
```

Now open `index.html` and see in browser console:

```
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old. I saw it on Google. Now we have better solutions to compile ClojureScript since 2017. shadow-cljs has a better experience of compiling, like Webpack, you may read the tutorial I gathered.

https://medium.com/@jiyinyiyong/a-beginner-guide-to-compile-clojurescript-with-shadow-cljs-26369190b786

and find more details in http://shadow-cljs.org .